# How can I compare file line to strings with placeholders?

Tags: java, file-io, string-comparison

I'm looking to compare a line from a file to a String with a placeholder.

The file contains a list of used `COM`, `ACM`, `USB` ports from the computer (Windows and Linux machines), and I want to add `COMx`, `ACMx`, `USBx` to a LinkedList where x is the port number assigned by the computer.

I was doing:

```java
// LinkedList<string> addr instantiated before.

// This if structure is inside a while loop reading each line of the file
// and storing it to line that breaks when line = null. Line is set to
// lower case for processing purposes.

if(line.contains("com") || line.contains("acm") || line.contains("usb"))
{
    addr.add(line);
}
```

and it would add `COM6` and `COMBluetooth Device`. What I'm looking for is a way to get just the `COM6` and not the `COMBluetooth Device` port, or really any other port that isn't numbered and then add this `COMx` substring to the addr list.

I've been led to believe that I can do this with formatted placeholders, but how would I integrate this into this `if` statement? And if not placeholders, how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you mean COM, ACM, USB ... as placeholders?

Comment: @Bastida I mean the `line.contains("com%d")` where the `%d` could be whatever number is next in the string after the substring "com". I don't know what this number would be between computers, as they change, which kinda takes hard coding a magic number out of the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this method:

```
private static boolean getResult(String line) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(COM|ACM|USB)\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    return m.find();
}
```

If you need to add more ports you can add `(COM|ACM|USB|nextPort|next|next)` and so on

Comment: Thanks for the help, the only issue I had was that `line` was lower case, and the regex pattern was in all caps. After changing the regex to lower case, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Another solution could be cast line to lower case using line.toLowerCase() when I use p.matcher(line);